# Writing a multifactor authentication provider for #LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, multi-factor-authentication

If I'm on #LinkedIn and I go to *Account -> Login and Security* there is an option for *Two-step Verification*. This is in addition to e.g. *Email Addresses* and *Telephone Numbers* (the latter clearly labeled "... in case you have trouble signing in").

However *Two-step Verification* also provides *SMS* (telephone) authentication in addition to an "authenticator app" option, "...such as *Microsoft Authenticator*". There is smoke here; is there fire?

How do I write my own authenticator: I presume there's a (REST) API (client / server, don't care)? How do I get #LinkedIn to call it (or vice versa)? Are there any examples?

**General Background** I'm envisioning two potential solutions: 1) a desktop app, tied to a particular desktop computing platform; 2) a deck of playing cards (seriously, and I've got POC for this). This is NOT using LinkedIn to login somewhere else, but providing custom MFA when logging in to LinkedIn. I'd probably try to write it in Python.

**Request Background (IMPORTANT)** I posed this question to #LinkedIn support, and they sent me here.

**Security Background (IMPORTANT)** SMS is not secure. There are ways of hijacking IMEIs. There are technical problems (bugs). There are other problems, for instance documented cases of bribery of telco personnel.

**Political Background (IMPORTANT)** #LinkedIn periodically asks me for a telephone number for MFA (multifactor authentication), but they have an email address; they could use that. There is documented past history of social networks using things like telephone numbers, provided for security purposes, to expand their social graph (in the legal sense, unauthorized conversion). Just like Certificate Authorities, there is no compelling technical reason that MFA can't be provided via open standards (in the case of CAs, DNSSEC and DANE as an alternative).

Comment: A bit too much packed in there buddy. It is unlikely many would read everything you provided. Also try to focus on only 1 question. I would suggest checking out [tour] and [ask] as well.

Comment: How do I write my own authenticator. It's pretty simple, buddy. I've heard "just use SMS" too many times; can't ask the question without speaking to it. If it doesn't get answered, I'll go back to LinkedIn support, but at least I did what they asked.